# Set new focused item in a List Box

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

I have a question. Is it true that in Access 2010 we can read which item in a list box has Focus. By focus I mean that little rectangle that is around current item. This is not a selected item. Selected item is highlighted. By clicking on List Box we set focus on an item and also select it. When selection is changed the focus stays there.

The property that indicates the index of that item is I believe .ListIndex. I would like to programmatically change it but unfortunately .ListIndex is read-only in Access 2010. Is there any other way I can do it?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to change it to?

Comment: In a listbox where multiselect is not set, there is no difference between focus and selected. You can set the value by using the data of the bound column: `Me.MyList = "June"`

Comment: .@Remou It's doing what I need now :) It changes this b$%^&*dy focus rectangle with selection. Thanks. Add it as an answer and I give you +1 and an answer, if that's important for you :)
Perhaps You could also comment on one of other questions, If I may ask or try to read my thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629102/list-box-items-not-highlighted-when-clicking-on-them). It's about the problem of clicking on a list box which is not highlighted :/ I gave up    Thanks

.@OverMind well It's been found confusing and I want highlighting goes with focus on item. It's working now